# why does HTML Tag not working in Post and Page

Tags: posts, pages, html

Though this is not a programming related question but I am facing a bitter experience with this WordPress problem. the problem is HTML Tags are not working in my website. See the images

[image: This is text Part]

[image: This is Visual part]

[image: This is how it publish]

Comment: Possibly the theme doesn't allow HTML and strips it out using functions like e.g. [`esc_html`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) or [`wp_kses`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses)

Comment: How to make sure that?

Comment: Yes, We can add .html into wordpress Page and post. i am already use this plugin.
Check Code Here : [wordpress html url free plugin](https://github.com/jnext-Wp-Plugin/Wordpress-html-into-url-free-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the theme that's how TinyMCE editor works. If you remain on the "Text" tab and update the post then the html will remain untouched and display properly on the front-end. However if you switch back to the "visual editor" it will break.

Here, you can use this on your functions.php

```
    // Modify Tiny_MCE init
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'smartenTinyMCE' );
function smartenTinyMCE($init) {
    // Add PRE and CODE to the block formats menu
    $init['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,code';

    // Allow extra attributes for some syntax highlighters, IE: <pre lang="php" line="5">...</pre)
    // Allow iFrames for live examples
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'pre[*]';

    return $init;
}
```

Source: https://provideyourown.com/2011/how-to-insert-code-into-your-wordpress-blog/

PS: You can add more separated by comma example:

```
$init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'pre[*],code[*],iframe[*]';
```

Comment: Its getting worse now. Visual part is showing nothing :-(  Nor in Front End.

Comment: Please switch to the updated code i tested on live site it's working.

Comment: Its not working till now. I am also working on a Live site. http://dccss.org/%E0%A6%AB%E0%A6%9F%E0%A7%8B-%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BF/

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens. Sorry, maybe someone else knows best.